# How to use stop-limit in Strategy

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to place a stop-limit order in my strategy-script but failed to do so.

```
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, limit=high[1]+10)
```

I want a market buy order to be placed when the price is above 10 points previous candle. 
previous candle `high - 200` 
order to be placed if price crosses `210`

Answer (score 3):

i just figured it out

```
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, stop=high[1]+10)
```

you have to use stop instead of limit for placing a stop-limit order

Comment: Yes, I just was writing this for you :)

Answer (score 2):

At PineScript V5, `Strategy.entry` has some quirks. Setting `limit`, `stop`, or both parameters will give you different results.

At least for V5, your answer in fact didn't give you a stop-limit. You get a market order with a simple stop loss at market. If you really want a stop-limit, probably you want to set `stop` and `limit` parameters.

Below, some explained examples for each case.

---

#### No `limit` or `stop` parameters

A simple market order.

```pine
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true)
```

---

#### `limit` without `stop` parameter

A simple Limit order. Placed to be executed when a advantageous price is reached.

```pine
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, limit=high[1]+10)
```

---

#### `stop` without `limit` parameter

A Stop order. Which is kind of a limit order, but placed in a disadvantageous price.

```pine
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, stop=high[1]+10)
```

---

#### Both `stop` and `limit` parameters

A market order with stop-limit stop loss.

```pine
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, limit=high[1]+10, stop=high[1]+20)
```

This last one will result in a market order with a trigger for a Stop-Limit order. In other words, it placed and when `stop` price is reached, a limit order at `limit` price will be placed. It's possible the order could not be fulfilled.